Taking out a slider to install a door window
I want to remove an 8‘ x 81“ slider and install a 48 x 36 window and a 36 inch exterior door to install the door. I have to cut up into a 4 x 12 supporting just above the slider to accommodate the 36 inch exterior door With enough support. Can I cut into that 4 x 12?

Only if you want to wear the house as a hat.  Why does the supporting header need cutting?

To accommodate the height 81 1/2 inches of a rough in space for the 36 inch exterior door

You can not just cut, it has a function so first find out what it is
